# How to open image map file (.map) in GIMP

Tags: html, images, gimp

I'm trying to create a large HTML image map in GIMP, using the Image Map tool (Filters > Web > Image Map).

I started on it yesterday and saved the file, it saved as a .map file. I'm trying to open it today to make some changes, but when I try to open it with GIMP, it gives me an error saying "Unknown file type".

How can I open the image map file that I saved?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open GIMP
2. Open the image for which the map belongs
3. Open the image map filter (Filters->Web->Image Map)
4. In the image map dialog, do File->Open and choose your map file

This should solve it :)